# String Manupilation and Left Join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, substring, left-join

So i have a table named ajar and a column named ajar_id:
and another table named branch_id and column id:

inside ajar_id privileges are stored and the format is like as follows:

```
`
+-----------------------+
| ajar_id               |
+-----------------------+
| ["1"]                 |
| ["1"]                 |
| ["1"]                 |
| ["1"]                 |
| ["1"]                 |
| ["1"]                 |
| ["1"]                 |
| ["1"]                 |
| ["1"]                 |
| ["4","6"]             |
| ["2","3","4","5","6"] |
| ["6"]                 |
| ["2","3","4","5"]     |
+-----------------------+
`
```

and i want to left join them with ajar table, inside this table privileges are stored like

```
`
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
|  8 |
|  9 |
| 10 |
| 11 |
+----+
`
```

I tried some sub string index methods but it didn't work.
How can i get the format as i wanted from first table's column and left join them with the second table's column?

Comment: What database are you using? That is, is it MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, or MS SQL?

Comment: it is MySQL and I am new to the company. Just working on the test server now.

Comment: I think you'll need to use `regexp` operator to do the matching. Something like: `select *
from first_table
left join second_table on (first_table.ajar_id regexp concat('.*"', second_table.id, '".*'));`.

Comment: Well that doesn't query. all it does is print all the table.

Comment: I think I previously misunderstood your query. Instead of left joining first table with second table you want to left join second table with first table, correct? If so, try this: `select * from second_table left join first_table on (first_table.ajar_id regexp concat('.*"', second_table.id, '".*'));`. I tried this on my computer and I think I'm getting the correct results.